# Oracle SQL Syntax Error - missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a line of one of my insert statements, it keeps throwing a missing comma error - however Im either blind as a bat or going stupid?!

```
INSERT INTO barrister (barrister_id,firstname,surname,telephone,email_address)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR sq_barrister, 'John', 'Smith',
            '01392345465', 'john_smith@wtflawers.com');
```

Comment: this "next value for" is correct?? It shouldn't be "sq_barrister.nextval"??? I think that is the problem

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm) did you find `next value for`?

Comment: @RaulLuna you're absolutely right, so post an answer, not a comment! :)

Comment: @DaveCosta I put a comment because I wasn't sure this was that easy!

Answer (score 3):

Raul is right. NEXT VALUE FOR is from SQL Server. In Oracle, use

```
sq_barrister.nextval
```